# How can I query documents where a values match a parent object and child object?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to Mongoose and I've been trying for days on how to solve this issue and I'm still having trouble.

My document object is below.

```
"person" : [
  {
    "title" : "front-end developer",
    "skills" : [
      {
        "name" : "js",
        "project" : "1",
      },
      {
        "name" : "CSS",
        "project" : "5",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title" : "software engineer",
    "skills" : [
      {
        "name" : "Java",
        "project" : "1",
      },
      {
        "name" : "c++",
        "project" : "5",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What I would like accomplish is to return all documents that have `person.title` = `software engineer` **AND** `person.skills.name` = `c++`. The skill `c++` has to **belong** to the `software engineer` person object. So returning documents when a front-end developer has `c++` is not ideal.

Here's what I've tried doing so far. The query works but it returns documents which meet either one of the conditions and not both.

```
var query = {
  _id: { $nin: [userID] },
    $and: [
      {person:  {
        $elemMatch: {
          name: {$regex: `^${titleName}$`, $options: "i"}
      }
    }},
    {[`person.skills`]:  {
      $elemMatch: {
        name: {$regex: `^${skillName}$`, $options: "i"}
      }
    }}
   ]
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query. Move the and condition inside the `$elemMatch`

```
var query = {
  "_id": {
    "$nin": [userID]
  },
  "person": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "name":{$regex: `^${titleName}$`, $options: "i"},
      "skills.name": {$regex: `^${skillName}$`, $options: "i"}
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much @Veeram, I didn't know you could insert dot notation inside of an elemmatch! I appreciate your help! :)